# using System.Data.OleDb; I cannot include the library in my project

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

using System.Data.OleDb; I cannot include the library in my project. Since I cannot include the relevant library in my project, I cannot make a database connection.

[image]

I tried to solve the problem by examining ready-made projects, but I am probably getting this error due to the version difference.

Comment: Post the code and any errors as *text*. Right now we can't guess what the error message is, just that your editor marked some lines

Comment: BTW the code you posted is outside any methods. You're trying to declare class-level fields containing objects that are only meant to exist inside *short* functions. Even if your code compiles this will generate serious problems. I'm pretty sure all the projects you examined declared connections and commands inside `using` blocks, to ensure they're disposes as quickly as possible

Comment: I suggest checking the ADO.NET documentation and [Create a simple data application by using ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-by-using-adonet?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). The only thing that needs to change is the type of connections and commands, ie SqlConnection to OleDbConnection etc. Connections are only defined and opened inside using blocks, to ensure they're closed when the method exits. This will release any locks taken during a connection and reduce blocking between clients